# souphttpclientsink plugin crash

Tags: ios, gstreamer

I am running the gstreamer pipeline using souphttpclient sink plugin on iOS platform (iPhone 6 with iOS 10.2. It crashes after several tries of stopping and restarting the pipeline back.

This is how I configure the souphttpclientsink plugin:

```
souphttpclientsink name=soup_sink location= https://<serverIP:port>/g711.cgi 
retries=20 retry-delay=1 max-lateness=250000000
```

The crash occurs when the souphttpclientsink plugin gets a signal to stop, which results g_main_loop_run of souphttpclientsink plugin to return. On returning, it seems to perform some IO reads and tries to reallocate memory which is not being allocated. 
Here is the exact message I see:

```
SoupHttpClientApp(1331,0x16e043000) malloc: *** error for object 0x1013437e0: pointer 
being realloc'd was not allocated*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Attached is the call stack of the crash.[image]

I ran the same test for hours on Windows platform and did not reproduce the issue. It seems the some resources are getting freed way before the souphttpclientsink plugin is aborting the session on the setting pipeline state to NULL.

I would really appreciate if you can provide any pointers on how to fix this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to see what's happening using the `GST_DEBUG` variable. Run the same thing on Linux with valgrind.

Comment: I ran the same thing on Windows and it runs for hours without the crash. This only happens in iOS platforms. Methinks some resources are getting freed in stop path of souphttpclientsink plugin asynchronously before the data's read or being read.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. For benefit of others, here is what fixed the souphttpclientsink crash on the iOS platform. Following code snippet of gst_soup_http_client_sink_stop function should be executed post g_thread_join on the souphttpclientsink-thread. Methinks its a timing issue on slower mobile processors and happen to read data after the session's aborted. This fix basically allows all remaining data to be handled by the main loop and returned gracefully before the soup session is aborted.

```
if (souphttpsink->prop_session == NULL) {
    soup_session_abort (souphttpsink->session);
    g_object_unref (souphttpsink->session); }
```

Hope it helps others!